# How I can delete the unnecessary part of the ERROR message

Tags: java, spring-boot

[I need to delete the name of the method in which this message falls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyT3a.png)

This is the code of my annotation

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ImageValidator.class)

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Documented
public @interface ImageValidation {

    String message() default "Download PNG or JPEG only."; **// Here is my message without a method name**

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

I need to delete the name of the method in which this message falls.

ERROR ::: [javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: **updateUserProfilePicture.image:** Download PNG or JPEG only.]

Comment: Have you tired a try-catch block around the code block that is causing the error and printing the exception message (`e.getMessage()`)? You could then delete everything in the string after "...Exception:" before concatenating your string message

Comment: What library/framework is this using?

Comment: I using Spring Boot, first I created  `class ImageValidator` which implemented `implements ConstraintValidator<ImageValidation, MultipartFile>` , after that I connect this class with my annotation

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Can't you just extract this from the details of the `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` (eg through `getConstraintViolations()`)?